# GetTwinAsync returns a device with null properties

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to read the twin of my device from the registry manager. This is my code:

```
DeviceClient client = 
DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString, 
TransportType.Mqtt);

Twin deviceTwin = await deviceClient.GetTwinAsync();
Console.WriteLine(deviceTwin.ToJson());
```

However, the Json I'm getting is the following.

```
{"deviceId":null,"etag":null,"version":null,"properties":{"desired":{"$version":1},"reported":{"$version":1}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your issue.

For this problem, you can open an issue on [azure-iot-sdk-csharp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp) repository.

For workarounds, you can either use REST API like this:

[image]

Or use Azure IoT Service SDK like this:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;

...

 var client = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(IoTHubConnectionString);
 var twinData = await client.GetTwinAsync(deviceId);
 Console.WriteLine(twinData.ToJson());
```

Comment: Thanks! Both options gives me what I need. :)

Comment: I'm curious, this still appears to be an issue (just broke my code as well, almost three years later) and an odd thing to have to "work around". Why would the module twin on the device be empty like this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue and/or workaround. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.gettwinasync?view=azure-dotnet) states:

> Retrieve the device twin properties for the current device. For the complete device twin object, use Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager.GetTwinAsync(string deviceId).